# Error: read ENOTCONN, Nodejs after running loadtest

Tags: node.js, npm, load-testing

I have created a simple express server, the code is attached below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/one', (req, res) => {
    console.log('received one request');
    const sum = longComputation();
    res.send({sum: sum})
});
app.listen(5632, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Server listening on 5632...`)
});

function longComputation(){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i < 1e9; i++){
        sum += i; 
    }
    return sum
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I call the API using browser/postman, but if I call using "loadtest -n 10 -c 10 http://localhost:5632/one" command (loadtest npm package) it throws the below error.

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ENOTCONN
    at tryReadStart (node:net:674:20)
    at Socket._read (node:net:685:5)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:12)
    at Socket.read (node:net:741:39)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:999:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4053,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I have node version 18 and above, so I have globally installed loadtest npm package latest version 5.2.0 Still it is not working.

Comment: i mean... why loadtest logic that'd never exist in a modern application? synchronous logic like that should never run in a place that would hold up processing of future requests. It's not surprising that you'd run into a timeout.

Comment: I followed a tutorial and wanted to perform a heavy computation function written in synchronous, asynchronous and fork style(child process). I have written three get requests for comparison. Problem is loadtest request is not even connecting to the server, but the same code works perfectly fine with loadtest in another computer.

Comment: This test is certainly hardware bound, you're not really testing anything interesting with this test. a loop like this blocks the main thread and prevents all handling of other requests in node.js. All requests will be handled one by one, and eventually, assuming it takes the server long enough to run the synchronous code, all of the pending requests will timeout. The "solution" of course is to not have a synchronous loop of this nature running directly on the node.js server that is handling incoming requests.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem

Comment: With my observation, I faced the above issue in PC's with windows 10 OS. Strangely it worked without any issues in windows 11 OS

Comment: Do you find a way to fix it on window 10? @PoojaSeethur

Comment: Unfortunately I could not

Comment: I wonder if this is related: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/d54a1e9a575d15186c8e55a230fdd1b6f82cc951/cli/lib/exec/spawn.js#L253C12-L266